# Rounding off coordinates in an SpatialPolygonDataFrame in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates

After a comment of Whuber I realized it will probably be most easy to incorporate a round(...) statement within my code to be able to work with less decimals. Underneath I have added the functions I am using. My first function (allcoordinates) extracts all coordinates of a SPDF. My second function (transformloop) transforms in a loop. After every transformation I want to round off my coordinates. Simply using round(file@polygons, 2) or signif(file@polygons, 2) does not work. The polygons of a SPDF are not seen as numeric values apparently.

Does anybody know how to round off coordinates within a SPDF?

```
allcoordinates <- function(x) {
  ret <- NULL
  polys <- slot(x,"polygons")
  for(i in 1:length(polys)) {
    pp = polys[[i]]@Polygons
    for (j in 1:length(pp))
      ret = rbind(ret, coordinates(pp[[j]]))
  }
  ret
 }

transformloop <- function(inputfile, count){
  intermediate <- spTransform(inputfile, CRS("..."))
  inputfile <- spTransform(intermediate, CRS("..."))
  if (count==0){
    return(inputfile)
  } else  
    newcount <- count-1
  transformloop(inputfile, newcount)      
}
```

I have added the first function cause I am thinking that possibly the best option is to extract the coordinates, round them off, and then replace the existing coordinates with the coordinates I rounded off.

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION (outdated):

In RStudio I am transforming data from coordinate system to coordinate system and back. Then I compare the coordinates of the original file with the endfile. This shows minor differences 7 digits behind the comma. However, I want to know what happens with the numbers if a system would work with less numbers behind the comma.

Within R I managed to find the code options(digits=...). This option only visualizes the numbers in a certain amount of digits. The calculation appears to do exactly the same. This is absolutely correct and usually a very good characteristic. But it is not what I want right now. I want it to be less accurate.

Is there a way to manipulate R in order for it to work with a different amount of numbers behind the comma constantly?

Comment: Transforming coordinates back and forth is generally not a good idea. If you are getting new attributes after the first transformation you may want to just update the original file with new data so your original coordinates will remain intact.

Comment: I know in general it is not a good idea to transform up and down. But I am researching the effects of the transformation. So for me it is exactly what I want.

Comment: I do not know how other systems work. Do they work with the same amount of numbers behind the comma as RStudio or not? Is this a general thing? Does it matter for the result of a transformation? - I assume so -

Comment: It looks like you really need to learn about how computers represent numbers and calculate with them. Start with articles on the [IEEE double-precision floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Once that is clarified, it should become apparent that the only way in `R` to control the *precision* of the arithmetic you do is through inserting statements to round intermediate values (`round`, *eg*). It's trickier than that, though, because you're really interested in the *total number* of decimals used, not just those after the comma.

Comment: Re the edit: (1) What's an "SPDF"? (2) I see no instance of `round` anywhere in the code. How, then, is it relevant to the edit? (3) Because changes in coordinate systems use documented formulas and information about scale factors is readily available, the effects of any small amount of imprecision (up to thousands of meters at least) can be accurately calculated in advance for any coordinate system. Have you considered taking that approach to studying this issue?

Comment: Well maybe I describe it incorrect. At that moment in time I figured I had to do something with round(). Now I am doubting. The tip you gave me which helped me further is that I should not try to adjust the system but round off in the code. So I would like to transform, round off coordinates, and transform again. However, it is not possible to round off the coordinates in the SpatialPolygonDataFrame(SPDF). So I am thinking of extracting them, rounding them off and then inserting them again. Extracting works, rounding off works, but I do not know how to insert them back again (yet!)